# New to VHDL, the unaffected waveform is not supported

Tags: concurrency, signals, vhdl, xilinx

I'm using VHDL, but my simulator doesnt support the unaffected waveform in the following example code which I need to have running before I can begin the homework assignment. I read online I can pass the same waveform Z, but I'm not sure how to do that so that I would get the same result as the unaffected keyword... How can it be rewritten so it produces the same result?

PS: I need to rewrite it using if-then-else statements in the next part of the homework, and I know I could use the next keyword in that case. This is code from a textbook that I need to run prior to the homework.

Thanks for your help.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity pr_encoder is
port (  S0, S1,S2,S3: in std_logic;
            Z : out std_logic_vector (1 downto 0));
end entity pr_encoder;

architecture behavioral of pr_encoder is
begin
    Z <= "00" after 5 ns when S0 = '1' else
    "01" after 5 ns when S1 = '1' else
    unaffected when S2 = '1' else
    "11" after 5 ns when S3 = '1' else
    "00" after 5 ns;
end architecture behavioral;
```

**edit: If i comment out the line, will I achieve my desired result?**

Answer (score 2):

No, if you simply comment the line with `unaffected` the behavior will be changed.

It seems you are describing a [latch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latch_%28electronics%29). (This is not recommended in synchronous designs). Indeed `Z` is updated if `S2 /= '1'` and is not if `S2 = '1'`.

You can indeed wrap your assignment in a process and a if-else structure but the `next` statement is not required.

```
process (S0, S1, S2, S3) is
begin
    if S0 = '1' then
        Z <= "00" after 5 ns;
    elsif S1 = '1' then
        Z <= "01" after 5 ns;
    elsif S2 = '1' then
        null;                 -- do nothing
    elsif S3 = '1' then
        Z <= "11" after 5 ns;
    else
        Z <= "00" after 5 ns;
    end if;
end process;
```

Or you can keep a *selected assignment statement* as you have now and change the conditions to make the `unaffected` the default (else) case.

```
Z <= "00" after 5 ns when S0 = '1' else
     "01" after 5 ns when S1 = '1' else
     "11" after 5 ns when S2 /= '1' and S3 = '1' else
     "00" after 5 ns when S2 /= '1';
     -- else unaffected is implicit
```

Side remarks:

I had never heard about the `unaffected` keyword before, I think it's usage is very limited thus it may not be supported by all tools?

What is your simulator ?